# Vue, SVG element doesn't updates in Firefox

Tags: firefox, svg, vuejs2

This is the example https://codesandbox.io/s/4xwv953mv0

There are three lines. The original one is hidden the second linked to it by id xlink:href="#line", the third links the second the same way.

Move the slider, the lines will go up in the Chrome, and only one will go up in the Firefox.

If it is a Firefox bug what to do? Is there a way to update SVG with Vue?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is a known Firefox bug.  [Firefox bug report here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1032124) and [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=467498).

There is a simple fix here though.  Just change your second use so that it points to the `<line>` directly, rather than at the `<use>`.

```
    <use
      id="Svg"
      xlink:href="#line"
      transform="translate(40,10)"
    ></use>
```

As an aside. I recommend that you put your line in a `<defs>` section, rather than hiding it with `display:none`.  This is what `<defs>` is for, and using `display:none` can have unintended consequences in some cases.

```
  <defs>
    <line
      id="line"
      x1="0"
      y1="0"
      x2="100"
      :y2="value"
      vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"
    />
  </defs>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to SVG didn't know about 'defs'. As for the link to the original one, this is my App [https://pastiche.design/editor](https://pastiche.design/editor)  That's what I'm doing - first (now in 'defs') I define one side, then populate it around and then create an array of the populated pattern. So double heritage looks like a right solution